# How to handle hive locking across hive and presto

Tags: hive, presto, trino

I have a few hive tables that are insert-overwrite from spark and hive. Those tables are also accessed by analysts on presto. Naturally, we're running into some windows of time that users are hitting an incomplete data set because presto is ignoring locks.

The options I can think of:

- Fork the presto-hive connector to support hive S and X locks appropriately. This isn't too bad, but time consuming to do properly.
- Swap the table location on the hive metastore once an insert overwrite is complete. This is OK, but a little messy because we like to store explicit locations at the database level and let the tables inherit location.
- Stop doing insert-overwrite on these tables and instead just add a new partition for the things that have changed, then once a new partition is written, alter the hive table to see it. Then we can just have views on top of the data that will properly reconcile the latest version of each row.
- Stop doing insert-overwrite on s3 which has a long window of copy from hive staging to the target table. If we move to hdfs for all insert-overwrite, we still have the issue, but it's over the span of time that it takes to do a hdfs mv which is significantly faster. (probably bad: there's still a window that we can get incomplete data)

My question is how do people generally handle that? It seems like a common scenario that would have an explicit solution, but I seem to be missing it. This can be asked in general for any third party tool that can query the hive metastore and interact with the hdfs/s3 directly while not respecting hive locks.

Comment: there's an open issue for handling ACID in Presto for Hive. https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/1970